# I want to compare one line to the next line, but only in the third column, from a file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

So, what I'm trying to do is read in a file, loop through it comparing it line by line, but only in the third column. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, but maybe this will help. I have a file of names:
 
 `JOHN SMITH SMITH
 JIM JOHNSON JOHNSON
 JIM SMITH SMITH`

I want to see if (first, col3)SMITH is equal to JOHNSON, if not, move onto the next name. If (first, col3) SMITH is equal to (second, col3) SMITH, then I'll do something with that. 
Again, I'm sorry if this doesn't make much sense, but I tried to explain it as best as I could.
I was attempting to see if they were equal, but obviously that didn't work. Here is what I have so far, but I got stuck:

```
while read -a line
do
    if [ ${line[2]} == ${line[2]} ]
    then
            echo -e "${line[2]}" >> names5.txt
    else
            echo "Not equal."
    fi
done < names4.txt
```

Comment: Quotes are important. `[ "${line[2]}" = "${old_line[2]}" ]`. And put something like `old_line=( "${line[@]}" )` at the end.

Comment: Note also that it's `=`, not `==`, if you want to be in good (POSIX-compliant) habits.

Comment: And don't use `echo -e` -- while its behavior by default breaks black-letter POSIX, that's runtime-configurable, so in some bash configurations it'll do the standards-compliant thing and just write `-e` to output. If you want something akin to `foo='hello\nworld'; echo -e "$foo"` to write `hello` and `world` on two different lines, then use `printf '%b\n' "$foo"`, as suggested by the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: You just want an array with the 3rd fields? Easy: `readarray -t third_fields < <(awk '{print $3}' names4.txt)`

Comment: though if you just want the unique names... `awk '{print $3}' names4.txt | sort -u` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Store your immediately prior line in a separate variable, so you can compare against it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

old_line=( )
while read -r -a line
do
    if [ "${line[2]}" = "${line[2]}" ]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${line[2]}" 
    else
            echo "Not equal." >&2
    fi
    old_line=( "${line[@]}" )
done <names4.txt >>names5.txt
```

---

Some other changes of note:

- Instead of re-opening `names5.txt` every time you want to write a single line to it, we're opening it just once, for the whole loop. (You could make this `>names5.txt` if you want to clear it at the top of the loop and append from there, which is likely to be desirable behavior).
- We're avoiding `echo -e`. See the APPLICATION USE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for background on why `echo` use is not recommended for new development when contents are not tightly constrained (known not to contain any backslashes, for example).
- We're quoting both sides of the `test` operation. This is mandatory with `[ ]` to ensure correct operation of words can be expanded as globs (ie. if you have a word `*`, you don't want it replaced with a list of files in your current directory in the final command), or if they can contain spaces (not so much a concern here, since you're using the same `IFS` value for the `read -a` as the unquoted expansion). Even if using `[[ ]]`, you want to quote the right-hand side so it's treated as a literal string and not a pattern.
- We're passing `-r` to `read`, which ensures that backslashes are not silently removed (changing `\t` in the input to just `t`, for example).

Comment: All it's doing for me is printing out the third column

Comment: @Gabi, that's what you asked for -- printing the 3rd column, if-and-only-if it's different from the 3rd column of the immediately prior line. ("one line to the next line" clearly indicates that you're comparing each line with the immediately following one, not with all other prior or following lines).

Comment: The test `if [ "${line[2]}" = "${line[2]}" ];` is always true. I think you wanted to write `if [ "${old_line[2]}" = "${line[2]}" ];`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare each third field with all previous third fields, you need to store the old third fields in an array. You can use `awk` for this.
When you only want to see the repeated third fields, you can use other tools:

```
cut -d" " -f3 names4.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

EDIT:
When you onlu want to print doubles from 2 consecutive lines, it is even easier:

```
cut -d" " -f3 names4.txt | uniq -d
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for, storing in an array. I cannot figure out how to do that!

Comment: When you only want to compare the last 2 lines, you do not need an array. For additional requirements you can look at `awk '$3==last {print $0 ": repeats the last field";} {last=$3; a[$3]++} END { print "Summary"; for (k in a) { print k " occurs " a[k] " time(s)." } }' names4.txt`.